# PDF - Mass cropping of non-whitespace application

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, whitespace, crop, trim

I have about 400 pdfs with a lot of dead space between the text and the page border.

Usually I'm using **[govert's pdf cropper](http://www.noliturbare.com/pdf-tools/pdf-cropper)** to crop all the whitespace, but this time the pdf background color is (darn!) **yellow**, 
and no software which I know (and I've searched for quite a while) can crop ***non-whitespace*** 
(well, except maybe **[pdfcrop.pl](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfcrop/)** -a Pearl library which supposedly can remove black spaces).

Anybody knows of a software that can perform such task?
The ideal app, I guess, would have the option to receive **specific color to remove**,
like rgb(192,192,192).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is so difficult is that PDF has no concept of paper color or background color. So what you're seeing is not a different background color, but an object (typically a rectangle) painted in that yellow background color.

Most cropping tools simply calculate the bounding box of all objects on the page and then crop away everything outside that bounding box. Of course that doesn't work for your file because the bounding box will include the background rectangle object.

There are potentially a number of directions you could take this:

1) If all pages need to be cropped by the same amount, you could attempt to do cropping that way (simply passing a rectangle to the cropping tool to do the actual cropping).

2) There are tools (callas pdfToolbox - watch it, I'm associated with this tool, Enfocus PitStop...) that allow you to remove objects from a document and this could be done by specifying your yellow color. This would allow you to modify the PDF file by removing the background object and then perform the cropping you want to perform.

Comment: Thanks David. I do have the same files with white background, perhaps do you know of a tool that can change pdfs background color in bulk? this way I could first crop them and then set the background to another color